# Why Apple Mail does not search based on sender email address?

Tags: mail.app

I search for `Alza` you can see, they sent me an email, but Mail does not show it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you rebuild your mail index and the spotlight index already? Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Mac 11.5.2 I think the latest.

Comment: I pressed "Read Account Infos", and also tried to search in the browser icloud interface, to avoid use local limited search capabilities. Without any success.

Comment: Sounds like [my answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/442523/164512) could help.